# how to initialize a BigInteger manually in JAVA at time of debug?

Tags: java, debugging, initialization, breakpoints, biginteger

I try to use following code to initialize a ***BigInteger*** at time of compiling (using breakpoint) in JAVA. So, I cannot use `BigInteger x = new BigInteger(String str);` because this is at time of debug the code by breakpoint.

the code:

```
BigInteger x = BigInteger.valueOf(36894801013086644936129270378595901597221307673940538800722758616305130630160);
```

error:

***The literal 36894801013086644936129270378595901597221307673940538800722758616305130630160 of type int is out of range.***

If I use `BigInteger x = new BigInteger(String str);` and then run the code, it will be OK, but I want to debug the code by some breakpoint and initialize *BinInteger x* (or change previous value of **x**) manually at time of debug.

The problem is that x keeps its previous value regardless to new value. apparently, only the "first initialization" value is kept. But, I want to change it to another value at time of debug, by a new value that is : 36894801013086644936129270378595901597221307673940538800722758616305130630160.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: what's wrong if you select bigInteger and change value while debugging using `new BigInteger(...);`

Comment: The problem is that x keeps its previous value regardless to new value. apparently, only the "first initialization" value is kept. But, I want to change it to another value at time of debug, by a new value that is : 36894801013086644936129270378595901597221307673940538800722758616305130630160.

Comment: I am la little confused ... You either set a value before you compile in your code, or maybe after using a debugger while debugging. It is also unclear to me how you change that value etc. Also both versions, valueOf or constructor, if one works for initializing then the other should also work. Does it work to use `valueOf` with a smaller value, let's say `100`?

Comment: assume that at time of starting debug x has a value like this :
61401226677452992711425049800588498075065303305358790151225727948455658750462
and there is a breakpoint exactly in top of x
then I want to change value of x by another value like this:
36894801013086644936129270378595901597221307673940538800722758616305130630160
there is function that x is its parameter
after this change, when breakpoint arrives this function, the value of x is yet previous value that is:
61401226677452992711425049800588498075065303305358790151225727948455658750462
I hope that I could explain properly.

Comment: 'There is function' ... What function? Maybe you need to show the code fragment where you are setting the breakpoint. Possibly also document the IDE you are using for your debugging session.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I found a solution to do my test. I needed the value of BigInteger in another class that I changed the type of BigInteger to public static. So, I think now it would be better I delete my question.